# MySQL Rows deleted without any apparent cause

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a question which is driving me really crazy...

I've created a PHP / MySQL website and, among the others, I have a MySQL table called "offers".

Sometimes one or more rows (never all together) disappear from this table, as if they were cancelled...

There are two ways to cancel offers, one is the command "DELETE FROM offers WHERE id = '$id'" which I did not use, so this option is excluded.

The other one is a command "DELETE FROM offers WHERE expiry_date < '$now'" which, of course, delete expired offers. The thing is that sometimes even not-expired offers are deleted.

I really cannot understand why those rows tend to disappear.

This happens without any solution of continuity... sometimes it happens twice a day, sometimes once a week, sometimes once every 3 months... never at the same time and never at the same day of the week.

I've started to think it can depend (in some way I don't understand) from the server, but I'm don't know this field very well to be honest so mine is just an assumption.

Hope someone of you guys will be able to help me or at least give me some hint.

Wait for your kind replies, many thanks in advance.

Dean.

Comment: A hacker accessin your database for fun because he got the password? Maybe someone close to you? Change the passwords!

Comment: Funny comment above, but it's probably not the case. I'm guessing `'$now'` should not be a String.

Comment: Where's your code? Both your queries have a potential for SQL injection unless you have properly sanitised your variables. If not, almost anything could happen.

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, what do you mean?

Comment: MySQL prepared statements help to guard against SQL injection. You should also look into XSS injection.

Comment: @Dean - also, there's little advantage in deleting things from the database if they're expired - just make sure that you only display current offers, and you have the same net effect. This will also remove one of the possible causes of your issue

Comment: It may be worth having an on delete trigger that will record when rows are deleted. If the rows are being explicitly deleted you can find out when and why. If they go missing without being recorded then you may have found a 'bug'?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe replace php $now by a mysql NOW() ?
e.g. `DELETE FROM offers WHERE expiry_date < NOW();`

If you don't have any other "DELETE" operations or UPDATE, or no MySQL transactions you have some choices :

- a colleague is playing with your nerves
- a hacker
- wrong WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks for your comments guys... I will definitively exclude both hackers and colleagues, probably the WHERE clause. I'll try to change "$now" with "NOW()" and keep a constant eye on the situation to see if it happen again...

Comment: good luck man, try to make some sql testing to see the different cases